# item not saving to shopping-cart node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

when i try to add an item to the shopping cart

appears this error in the screen https://prnt.sc/t08epi

this is my cart models file:

```
module.exports = function Cart(oldCart) {
this.items = oldCart.items || {};
this.totalQty = oldCart.totalQty || 0;
this.totalPrice = oldCart.totalPrice || 0;

this.add = function (item, id) {
    var storedItem = this.items[id];

    if (!storedItem) {
        storedItem = this.items[id] = { item: item, qty: 0, price: 0 }
    }

    storedItem.qty++;
    storedItem.price = storedItem.item.price * storedItem.qty; //sub total
    this.totalQty++;
    this.totalPrice += storedItem.item.price; //total
}
```

}

this is my router cart:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Product = require('../models/Product');
var Cart = require('../models/Cart');

router.get('/add-to-cart/:id', (req, res, next) => {

var productId = req.params.id;
var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : { items: {} });
Product.findById(productId, (err, product) => {
    if (err) return res.redirect('/');
    cart.add(product, product.id);
    req.session.cart = cart;
    res.redirect('/');

});

});

module.exports = router;
```

my app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressHbs = require ('express-handlebars');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var validator = require('express-validator');
var passport = require('passport');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);





var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var cartRouter = require('./routes/cart');
var dbConfig = require ('./database/db');


var app = express();

mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url,{useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology:true});
require('./config/passport');
```

// view engine setup

```
 app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({defaultLayout: 'layout' , extname:'.hbs'}));
```

//app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

```
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(validator());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  secret: 'mySecretPassword',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
  cookie: { maxAge: 120 * 60 * 60 }
}));


app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use((req,res,next)=>{
res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
res.locals.session = req.session;
next();
})

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/user', usersRouter);
app.use('/cart', cartRouter);
```

// catch 404 and forward to error handler

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});
```

// error handler

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
```

// set locals, only providing error in development

```
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
```

// render the error page

```
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

my store.hbs

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row mt-5">
    {{#each productsDocuments }}

    <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                games available
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <img src={{ this.imagePath }} alt="" class="img-fluid zoom" style="height: 200px;">
                <hr />
                <h3>{{ this.title }}</h3>
                <p class="description">{{ this.description }}</p>
                <div class="price">
                    ${{ this.price }}
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-1">
                        <a href="/cart/add-to-cart/{{this.id}}" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg pull-right"
                            role="button">
                            <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {{/each}}
</div>
```

error log

NotFoundError: Not Found

```
    at D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping-cart\shopping-cart\app.js:66:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping-cart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping-cart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping-cart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping-cart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping-cart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping-cart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
    at next (D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping-cart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping-cart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping-cart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping-cart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping-cart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping-cart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping-cart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
   at next (D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping-cart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
   at D:\programfiles\vsprojects\shopping-cart\shopping-cart\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
```

i cant see what im doing wrong anyone can help?

Comment: What is your browser URL when it gives an error?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/cart/add-to-cart/

Comment: You are missing :id in the end. If you want to make it optional then add a question mark. `'/add-to-cart/:id?'`

Comment: i did that and still i have the same error

Comment: What happens when you add some number there, still give an error? `localhost:3000/cart/add-to-cart/12` for example

Comment: no it returns to localhost:3000

Comment: And that's correct. It is clearly written in your code when productId does not exist redirect to the main page which is '/'. It is doing fine I would say. No more NOT_FOUND error

Comment: yes the thing i dont know is why is not saving in shopping-cart when i click the cart button like this https://prnt.sc/t0tcz6

Comment: The problem you are not satisfied with is something else which you need to find in this function `Product.findById`. Some error happens there and then your function is redirecting to root dir. You need to check that logic.

Comment: maybe the problem is with my cart session ?

Comment: i cant seem to find it @harry

Comment: I cannot say that unless you update your question with `Product.findById` function content and all related stuff in it